# No recibo datos JSON

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tengo un problema al recibir datos JSON de un formulario conectado a una base de datos con campos (`id`, `nombre`, `numero`).

El problema surge cuando trato de editar un valor de la tabla y guardarlo y que debería actualizarse a través de XHR.

¿Alguien podría decirme qué error/es hay?

El error que da en consola es:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
>           at JSON.parse ()
>           at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange app.js377

**index.php**

```
<?php
   try {
        require_once('funciones/bd_conexion.php');
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM contactos'; 
        $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
   } catch (Exception $e) {
         $error = $e->getMessage();
   } 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Agenda PHP</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Proza+Libre" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css" media="screen" title="no title">
</head>
<body>
<div class="contenedor">
  <h1>Agenda de Contactos</h1>
  <div class="contenido">
    <div id="crear_contacto" class="crear">
      <h2>Nuevo Contacto</h2>
      <form action="crear.php" method="post" id="formulario-crear-usuario">
        <div class="campo">
          <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
          <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
        </div>
        <div class="campo">
          <label for="numero">Teléfono:</label>
          <input type="text" name="numero" id="numero" placeholder="Número">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Agregar" id="agregar" class="boton">
      </form>

    </div>
    <!--.crear_contacto--> 
  </div>
  <!--.contenido-->

  <div class="contenido existentes">
    <div class="buscar">
      <h2>Buscar</h2>
      <input type="text" id="buscador" name="buscador" placeholder="Buscar" class="buscador">
    </div>
    <h2>Contactos Existentes</h2>
    <p>Resultados: <span id="total"><?php echo $resultado->num_rows; ?></span> </p>
    <table id="registrados">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Teléfono</th>
          <th>Editar</th>
          <th> <button type="button" name="Borrar" id="btn_borrar" class="borrar">Borrar</button>
            <input type="checkbox" id="borrar_todos">
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php //fetch_assoc, fetch_row, fetch_array, fetch_all, fetch_objects  ?>
        <?php while($registros = $resultado->fetch_assoc() ) { ?>
        <?php //dentro parentesis (MYSQLI_ASSOC, MYSQLI_NUM) ?>
        <tr id="<?php echo $registros['id']; ?>">   
          <td>
            <p><?php echo $registros['nombre']; ?></p>
            <input type="text" class="nombre_contacto" value="<?php echo $registros['nombre']; ?>" name="contacto_<?php echo $registros['id']; ?>">
          </td>
          <td>
            <p><?php echo $registros['numero']; ?></p>
            <input type="text" class="telefono_contacto" value="<?php echo $registros['numero']; ?>" name="telefono_<?php echo $registros['id']; ?>">
            </td>
          <td>
            <!--<a href="editar.php?id=<?php echo $registros['id']; ?>">Editar</a> cambia en v449-->
            <a href="#" class="editarBtn">Editar</a>
            <a href="#" class="guardarBtn">Guardar</a>
          </td>
          <td class="borrar"><input class="borrar_contacto" type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $registros['id']; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<?php 
    $conn->close();
?>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

En este archivo sobre todo el problema vendría en las dos últimas funciones `actualizarRegistro(idRegistro)` y `actualizarAjax(datosContacto)`.

**app.js**

```
var agregarContacto = document.getElementById('agregar');
var formulario = document.getElementById('formulario-crear-usuario');
var action = formulario.getAttribute('action');
var divCrear = document.getElementById('crear_contacto');
var tablaRegistrados = document.getElementById('registrados');
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('borrar_contacto');
var btn_borrar = document.getElementById('btn_borrar');
var tableBody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody');
var divExistentes = document.getElementsByClassName('existentes');
var inputBuscador = document.getElementById('buscador');
var totalRegistros = document.getElementById('total');
var checkTodos = document.getElementById('borrar_todos');

function registroExitoso(nombre){
    //crear div y agregar un id
    var divMensaje = document.createElement('DIV');
    divMensaje.setAttribute('id',"mensaje");

    //agregar texto
    var texto = document.createTextNode('Creado: ' + nombre);
    divMensaje.appendChild(texto);

    divCrear.insertBefore(divMensaje, divCrear.childNodes[4]);

    //agregar la clase mostrar
    divMensaje.classList.add('mostrar');

    //ocultar el mensaje de creacion
    setTimeout(function(){
        divMensaje.classList.add('ocultar');
        setTimeout(function(){
            var divPadreMensaje = divMensaje.parentNode;
            divPadreMensaje.removeChild(divMensaje);
        }, 500);
    }, 3000);
}
// construir template para insertar datos dinamicamente
function construirTemplate(nombre, telefono, registro_id){
    //crear nombre de contacto
    var tdNombre = document.createElement('TD');
    var textoNombre = document.createTextNode(nombre);
    tdNombre.appendChild(textoNombre);

    //crear telefono de contacto
    var tdTelefono = document.createElement('TD');
    var textoTelefono = document.createTextNode(telefono);
    tdTelefono.appendChild(textoTelefono);

    //crear enlace para editar
    var nodoBtn = document.createElement('A');
    var textoEnlace = document.createTextNode('Editar');
    nodoBtn.appendChild(textoEnlace);
    nodoBtn.href = 'editar.php?id=' + registro_id;

    //agregar el boton al td
    var nodoTdEditar = document.createElement('TD');
    nodoTdEditar.appendChild(nodoBtn);

    //crear checkbox para borrar
    var checkBorrar = document.createElement('INPUT');
    checkBorrar.type = 'checkbox';
    checkBorrar.name = registro_id;
    checkBorrar.classList.add('borrar_contacto');

    //agregar td a checkbox
    var tdCheckbox = document.createElement('TD');
    tdCheckbox.classList.add('borrar');
    tdCheckbox.appendChild(checkBorrar);

    //Crear Input con el nombre v449
    var inputNombre = document.createElement('INPUT');
    inputNombre.type = 'text';
    inputNombre.name = 'contacto_' + registro_id;
    inputNombre.value = nombre;

    //Crear Input con el telefono v449
    var inputTelefono = document.createElement('INPUT');
    inputTelefono.type = 'text';
    inputTelefono.name = 'contacto_' + registro_id;
    inputTelefono.value = nombre;

    tdNombre.appendChild(inputNombre);
    tdTelefono.appendChild(inputTelefono);

    //agregar al tr 
    var trContacto = document.createElement('TR');
    var idTr = trContacto.setAttribute('id', registro_id);//borrar ultimo
    var miId = trContacto.attributes[0].nodeValue;//borrar ultimo
    trContacto.appendChild(tdNombre);
    trContacto.appendChild(tdTelefono);
    trContacto.appendChild(nodoTdEditar);
    trContacto.appendChild(tdCheckbox);

    tablaRegistrados.childNodes[3].append(trContacto);

    //no viene en vid -> se mueve el for dentro del crearTemplate para que pinte en rojo un contacto añadido nuevo
    for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
        checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
            //console.log("has hecho click en un checkbox");
            if(this.checked){
                //console.log("Checkbox CHECADO");
                this.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add('activo');
            } else {
                console.log("Checkbox no CHECADO");
                this.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove('activo');
            }
        });
    }
}

function crearUsuario(){
    //alert("funciona");
    var form_datos = new FormData(formulario);
    for([key, value] of form_datos.entries()){
        console.log(key + ": " + value);
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', action, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            var resultado = xhr.responseText;
            console.log(resultado);
            var json = JSON.parse(resultado);
            //console.log(json.respuesta);
            if(json.respuesta == true){
                //alert("Contacto creado exitosamente");
                registroExitoso(json.nombre);
                construirTemplate(json.nombre, json.telefono, json.id);
                //añadido en v445
                var totalActualizado = parseInt(totalRegistros.textContent) + 1;
                totalRegistros.innerHTML = totalActualizado;
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.send(form_datos);
}

function mostrarEliminado() {
    // crear div y agregar id
    var divEliminado = document.createElement('DIV');
    divEliminado.setAttribute('id','borrado');

    //agregar texto
    var texto = document.createTextNode('Eliminado de lista de contactos');
    divEliminado.appendChild(texto);

    divExistentes[0].insertBefore(divEliminado, divExistentes[0].childNodes[0]);

    //agregar clase de CSS
    divEliminado.classList.add('mostrar');

    //ocultar el mensaje de borrado
    setTimeout(function() {
        divEliminado.classList.add('ocultar');
        setTimeout(function() {
            var divPadreMensaje = divEliminado.parentNode;
            divPadreMensaje.removeChild(divEliminado);
        }, 500 );
    }, 3000);
}

function eliminarHTML(ids_borrados){
    console.log("Id a borrar: " + ids_borrados);
    for(i = 0; i < ids_borrados.length; i++){
        var elementoBorrar = document.getElementById(ids_borrados[i]);
        tableBody[0].removeChild(elementoBorrar);
    }
}

function contactosEliminar(contactos){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'borrar.php?id=' + contactos, true);
    console.log('borrar.php?id=' + contactos);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            var resultadoBorrar = xhr.responseText;
            var json = JSON.parse(resultadoBorrar);
            if(json.respuesta == false) {
                alert("selecciona un elemento");
            } else {
                console.log("Resultado: " + resultadoBorrar);
                //console.log('SQL' + json.sql);
                eliminarHTML(contactos);
                mostrarEliminado();
                var totalActualizado = parseInt(totalRegistros.textContent) - json.borrados;
                totalRegistros.innerHTML = totalActualizado;
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

function checkboxSeleccionado() {
    var contactos = [];
    for(i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
        if(checkboxes[i].checked  == true){
            contactos.push(checkboxes[i].name);
        }
    }
    //console.log(contactos);
     contactosEliminar(contactos);
}

//añadido lesli
for(var i =0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change',function(){
//console.log("Has seleccionado un checkbox");
if(this.checked){
this.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add('activo');
//console.log("Checkbox checado");
}else{
// console.log("Checkbox no checado");
this.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove('activo');
}
});
}//fin añadido

agregarContacto.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    crearUsuario();
});

btn_borrar.addEventListener('click', function(){
    checkboxSeleccionado();
});

function actualizarNumero(){
    var registros = tableBody[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');

    var cantidad = 0;
    var ocultos = 0;

    for( var i = 0; i < registros.length; i++) {
        var elementos = registros[i];
        if(elementos.style.display == 'table-row'){
            cantidad++;
            totalRegistros.innerHTML = cantidad;
        } else {
            if(elementos.style.display == 'none') {
                ocultos++;
                if(ocultos == registros.length) {
                    ocultos -= registros.length;
                    totalRegistros.innerHTML = ocultos;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//vid443
function ocultarRegistros(nombre_buscar){
    //console.log(nombre_buscar);
    //variable para todos los registros
    var registros = tableBody[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');

    //expresion regular que busca el nombre con case insensitive (i)
    var expression = new RegExp(nombre_buscar, "i");

    for(var i = 0; i < registros.length; i++){
        registros[i].classList.add('ocultar');//added in v447
        registros[i].style.display = 'none';

        if(registros[i].childNodes[1].textContent.replace(/\s/g, "").search(expression) != -1 || nombre == '') {
            registros[i].classList.add('mostrar');
            registros[i].classList.remove('ocultar');
            registros[i].style.display = 'table-row';
        } //else if(nombre == '') {
            //registros[i].style.display = 'table-row';}
    }
    actualizarNumero();
}

inputBuscador.addEventListener('input', function() {
    //console.log(inputBuscador.value);
    ocultarRegistros(this.value);
});

//Seleccionar todos
checkTodos.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(this.checked){
        var todosRegistros = tableBody[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
        for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
            checkboxes[i].checked = true;
            todosRegistros[i].classList.add('activo');
            }
        } else {
            var todosRegistros = tableBody[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
                checkboxes[i].checked = false;
                todosRegistros[i].classList.remove('activo');
        }
    }
});

/*** Editar registros ***/

function recorrerBotonesEditar(){ //v450
    var btn_editar = tableBody[0].querySelectorAll('.editarBtn');
    //console.log(btn_editar);

    for(var i = 0; i < btn_editar.length; i++) {
        btn_editar[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            deshabilitarEdicion(); //v451

            //alert("hasta aqui bien");
            var registroActivo = this.parentNode.parentNode;
            //console.log(registroActivo);
            registroActivo.classList.add('modo-edicion');   
            registroActivo.classList.remove('desactivado'); 
            //console.log(registroActivo.id);

            //Actualizamos el registro en especifico (solo uno) v452
            actualizarRegistro(registroActivo.id);  
        });
    }
}

function deshabilitarEdicion(){
    var registrosTr = document.querySelectorAll('#registrados tbody tr');
    //console.log(registrosTr);
    for(var i = 0; i < registrosTr.length; i++){
        registrosTr[i].classList.add('desactivado');
    }
}

function actualizarRegistro(idRegistro){ //v452
    //console.log(idRegistro);
    //Seleccionar Boton de Guardar del Registro en especifico (se pasa el id)
    var btnGuardar = document.getElementById(idRegistro).getElementsByClassName('guardarBtn');
    //console.log(btnGuardar);
    btnGuardar[0].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //alert("Click en Guardar!");

        //Obtiene el valor del campo nombre
        var inputNombreNuevo = document.getElementById(idRegistro).getElementsByClassName('nombre_contacto');
        //console.log(inputNombreNuevo);
        var nombreNuevo = inputNombreNuevo[0].value;
        //console.log(nombreNuevo);

        //Obtiene el valor del campo de telefono
        var inputTelefonoNuevo = document.getElementById(idRegistro).getElementsByClassName('telefono_contacto');
        var telefonoNuevo = inputTelefonoNuevo[0].value;
        //console.log(telefonoNuevo);

        //objeto con todos los datos
        var contacto = {
            nombre: nombreNuevo,
            //telefono: telefonoNuevo, //esto fallaba
            numero: telefonoNuevo,
            id: idRegistro
        };
        //console.log(contacto);
        actualizarAjax(contacto); //v453

    });
}

function actualizarAjax(datosContacto){ //v453
    //console.log(datosContacto);
    //Convierte objeto a JSON
    var jsonContacto = JSON.stringify(datosContacto); 
    //console.log(jsonContacto);
    //crear la conexion
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'actualizar.php?datos=' + jsonContacto, true);
    //console.log('borrar.php?id=' + contactos);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            var resultado = xhr.responseText;
            //var json = JSON.parse(resultadoBorrar);
            var resultadoJson = JSON.parse(resultado);
            console.log(resultadoJson);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event){
    recorrerBotonesEditar();
});
```

**actualizar.php**

```
<?php
    function peticion_ajax(){
        return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest';   
    }

    $datos=$_GET['datos'];
    var_dump($datos);
    $datos=json_decode($datos,true);
    var_dump($datos);

   //$nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
   //$numero  =  $_GET['numero'];
   //$id = $_GET['id'];
   $nombre = $datos['nombre'];
   $numero  =  $datos['numero'];
   $id = $datos['id'];

   if(peticion_ajax()){
       try {
            require_once('funciones/bd_conexion.php');
            $sql = "UPDATE contactos SET ";   
            $sql .= "nombre= '{$nombre}', "; 
            $sql .= "numero = '{$numero}' ";
            $sql .= "WHERE id = {$id}";

            $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
            echo json_encode(array(
                'respuesta' => $resultado
            ));

       } catch (Exception $e) {
           $error = $e->getMessage();
       }

        $conn->close();
   } else {
       exit;
   }
?>
```

**estilos.css**

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:after, *:before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

body {
  background-color: orange;
}
.contenedor {
  max-width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
h1, h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Proza Libre', sans-serif;
}
div.contenido {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 30px auto 0 auto;
  font-size: 24px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;

}
h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
div.crear {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}

div.campo {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
div.campo label {
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
  margin-top:8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:right;
  margin-right:20px;
}
div.campo input{
    height:30px;
    width:70%;
    padding:10px;
}
.boton{
    background-color:orange;
    border:none;
    padding:10px 30px;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:white;
    font-size:16px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
div.buscar{
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
div.buscar h2{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.buscador{
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
}
span#total{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
}
div.existentes {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
div.existentes  table {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: geneva;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
div.existentes  table thead {
  background-color: #ff9800;
}
div.existentes table thead th {
    padding:10px 0;
}
div.existentes table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #9e9e9e;
}
div.existentes  table a {
  background-color: #3f51b5;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}
div.existentes  table td {
  padding: 10px 0;
  line-height: 20px;
}
div.existentes h2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
div.existentes p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
td.borrar a {
  background-color: red!important;
}

a.volver {
  color: orange;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

div#mensaje{
    margin-top:10px;
    border:1px solid green;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    background-color:green;
    color:white;
    font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    border-radius:10px;
    opacity:0;
}

div#borrado {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size 16px;
}

@keyframes mostrar{
    0% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1;}
}
@keyframes ocultar{
    0% {opacity:1;}
    100% {opacity:0;}
}
.mostrar {
    animation: mostrar .5s ease-in 1 forwards;
}
.ocultar {
    animation: ocultar .5s ease-in 1 forwards;
}
button.borrar {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
    background-image:url(../img/borrar.png);
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:25px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    display:block;
    height:25px;
    width:25px;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:10px;
}
td.borrar input {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
.activo{
    background-color: red!important;
}

/** Modo Edicion **/

.modo-edicion p,
.modo-edicion .editarBtn,
tbody tr input[type="text"],
div.existentes table tr a.guardarBtn {
    display: none;  
}
.modo-edicion input[type="text"],
div.existentes table tr.modo-edicion a.guardarBtn{
    display: block;
}
.desactivado {
    pointer-events:none;
    cursor: default;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

**bd_conexion.php**

```
<?php 
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'miweb');

    if($conn->connect_error) {
      echo $error = $conn->connect_error;
    }

    function peticion_ajax(){
        return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest';
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un problema montando la consulta `GET` debido a que no escapas correctamente los datos:

```
xhr.open('GET', 'actualizar.php?datos=' + jsonContacto, true);
```

La forma correcta sería usando [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/encodeURIComponent):

```
xhr.open('GET', 'actualizar.php?datos=' + encodeURIComponent(jsonContacto), true);
```

En el PHP quita las dos líneas que ponen:

```
var_dump($datos);
```

Además, tal y como hemos descubierto las las pruebas hechas en los comentarios, deberás quitar la doble definición de la función `peticion_ajax` para evitar que se envíe un mensaje de error por definir dos veces la misma función.

Si no corriges el código y evitas que se envíen datos de depuración, textos de advertencia o error, en el PHP se generará información que no forma parte del JSON, impidiendo que tu código interprete lo generado por el PHP como un JSON válido.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu ayuda. La verdad sigue sin funcionar. He cambiado lo que comentas pero sigue dando el siguiente error en consola: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange app.js 377
La linea a que hace referencia es (es posible que lo posteado no coincida):
var resultadoJson = JSON.parse(resultado); 
¿que puede estar recibiendo mal? ¿tu lo has probado y te funcionaba? Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué navegador usas? ¿Podrías usar el inspector de red para comprobar qué te devuelve el PHP? No lo he probado porque no tengo los datos suficientes para reproducir tu código (como el esquema de la tabla), pero ese `<` del que se queja tiene la pinta de ser un mensaje de advertencia de PHP. Por cierto, `$resultado` no puede ser enviado tal cual sin obtener un registro de él y, sobre todo, deberías haber uso de consultas preparadas y no concatenar cadenas.

Comment: Si, uso Chrome y en el consola del navegador muestra lo que puse antes:
: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange app.js 377 La linea a que hace referencia es (es posible que lo posteado no coincida): var resultadoJson = JSON.parse(resultado);
Entiendo lo que veas que falta seguridad. Estoy probando este ejemplo de una manera sencilla para entender su funcionamiento. Lo que me preocupa realmente ahora es porque no pueda funcionar el cambio de los campos a traves de JSON.
Gracias

Comment: Bueno, por partes. Para empezar ve a la pestaña de "network" y allí verás la petición XHR y pulsando primero sobre ella y luego pulsando en la pestaña "response" podrás ver lo que te devuelve el PHP. Dime qué te devuelve para encontrar el error de PHP. Para continuar, te recomiendo usar un framework JavaScript como jQuery para lidiar mejor con estas tareas (sobre todo soporte homogéneo multi navegador). Por último, tu código no está bien blindado para tener en cuenta cualquier situación de error, por lo que la raíz del problema podrían ser varias cosas.

Comment: En cuanto pueda te digo una forma "matando-a-cañonazos" de evitar problemas con mensajes de error o advertencias y, cuando pueda (me vendría bien la definición de la tabla) te lo blindo con comprobaciones de error.

Comment: Gracias. El error que devuelve el PHP es:
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot redeclare peticion_ajax() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\actualizar.php:3) in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\MIWEB\bd_conexion.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />

Parece que en la conexion a la bd habia otra comprobacion de peticion ajax que interfiere. Al quitarla parece que funciona bien. Creo que tan solo va a ser eso. No pueden haber dos comprobaciones del tipo:
function peticion_ajax(){
  return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest';
 }
en la misma pagina?

Comment: la definicion de la tabla es muy simple: id(int), nombre(varchar) y numero(varchar). Por si quieres probar a ver si va definitivamente bien.

Comment: Al final era lo que me temía, un error o advertencias de PHP que no permitía enviar un JSON "limpio". En cuanto a la función, exacto, sólo se puede definir una función una única vez. Procura mantener las funciones en un PHP propio y usa `require_once` para que se incluyan una única vez, aunque uses el `require_once` varias veces. Yo, personalmente, preferiría encapsular las funcionalidades en clases. Te aconsejo que te acostumbres a usar la consola de depuración para comprobar este tipo de cosas. Y, sobre todo, insisto en que eches un vistazo a jQuery.

Comment: Entendido, funciona perfectamente ahora. Gracias

Comment: Hola @RicardoKra , ¿podrías marcar la respuesta como correcta para darla por finalizada? Gracias.